# angularjs: how to know all directive is ready

Tags: angularjs, directive

I want make sure all directives are ready. How to? Here is what I try, but not correct.

```
leafUi.factory('leafState', function($rootScope) {
    var unreadyUi = [], readyUi = [];
    return {
        unready: function(ui) {
            console.log(ui + ' unready');
            unreadyUi.push(ui);
        },
        ready: function(ui) {
            console.warn(ui + ' ready');
            readyUi.push(ui);
            if (readyUi.length === unreadyUi.length) {
                $rootScope.$broadcast('leafUiReady', 'all leaf ui component is ready');
                // unreadyUi = null;
                // readyUi = null;
            }
        }
    }
});

leafUi.directive('leafScroll', function($timeout, leafState, leafScroll) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        link: function(scope, ele, attrs, ctrl, transclude) {
            leafState.unready('leafScroll');
            // more code .....
            leafState.ready('leafScroll');
        }
    };
});

leafUi.directive('leafContent', function($timeout, leafState, leafScroll) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        link: function(scope, ele, attrs, ctrl, transclude) {
            leafState.unready('leafContent');
            // more code .....
            leafState.ready('leafContent');
        }
    };
});
// more directive.....
```

Here is an example log:

[image: example log]

From the log, we can know that directive ready and unready can be separated by other directive and length of `readyUi` has many chance to equal to `unreadyUi`.
So how can I assure all directives are ready?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps add another condition to what you define as `leafUiReady` could help you. Since the directives are loaded almost synchronously you get the logic that your `undreadyUi` and `readyUi` are almost always the same length during compilation.

Perhaps add logic like this to your `leafState` factory where you also look at the DOM ready-function.

```
leafUi.factory('leafState', function($rootScope) {
    var unreadyUi = [], readyUi = [];
    var domReady = false;
    angular.element(document).ready(function () {
        domReady = true;
        if (readyUi.length === unreadyUi.length) {
            $rootScope.$broadcast('leafUiReady', 'all leaf ui component is ready');
            // unreadyUi = null;
            // readyUi = null;
        }
    });
    return {
        unready: function(ui) {
            console.log(ui + ' unready');
            unreadyUi.push(ui);
        },
        ready: function(ui) {
            console.warn(ui + ' ready');
            readyUi.push(ui);
            if (domReady && readyUi.length === unreadyUi.length) {
                $rootScope.$broadcast('leafUiReady', 'all leaf ui component is ready');
                // unreadyUi = null;
                // readyUi = null;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Perhaps change some other logic to make this code a bit cleaner.